# Laravel - Get data from multiple table as seperate array

Tags: laravel

I have this **feeds** table:

[image]

and **feed_mappings** table:

[image]

I want to get all the data from **feeds** table and **feed_mappings** table which **id_feed** is 33.

Using following query I can get the data successfully:

```
$get_import_info = DB::table($get_db_name[0]->mysql_db_name . '.feeds')
->leftJoin($get_db_name[0]->mysql_db_name . '.feed_mappings', 'feed_mappings.id_feed', '=', 'feeds.id_feed')
->where('feeds.id_project', '=', $token)
    ->get();
```

But

I want to get the all the data from **feed_mappings** table as **seperate** array not together with **feeds** data but what I am getting all the data together is below:

[image]

Comment: You're using a join query, so it's expected to show all at once. Two seperate queries does it though?

Comment: @geertjanknapen Would you please show me example?

Comment: Do a query for both the `feeds` and `feed_mappings` seperately

Comment: You need more knowledge on how to define a table(primary key) and how to add a Foreign key to a child table.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam like ?